# HTML Canvas erratic movement after changig value via slider

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a problem when trying to adjust the movement speed of my canvas elements - updating the value via console works no problem, but when I do the same thing with a slider on the website, the elements start flickering.

This is the relevant JS:

```
function Particle() {
  this.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 800);
  this.y = y;
  this.vx = vx;
  this.vy = vy;
  //...

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  if(this.y == ground[this.x]) {
    this.vy = 0;
    ground[this.x] = this.y - 1;
  } else { this.y += this.vy; }
  //...

var gravityControl = document.getElementById("gravity-control");
gravityControl.oninput = function() {
  vy = this.value;
  for(var i in particles) {
    if(particles[i].vy > 0) {
      particles[i].vy = this.value;
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8mv44ze2/1/) Try to adjust the Gravity slider and see what I mean.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not converting the slider value to a `Number`, but instead when you add the new `vy` to `this.y`, it's using string concatenation. Change this:

```
gravityControl.oninput = function() {
  vy = this.value;
  for(var i in particles) {
    if(particles[i].vy > 0) {
      particles[i].vy = this.value;
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
gravityControl.oninput = function() {
  vy = +this.value; // coerce to number
  for(var i in particles) {
    if(particles[i].vy > 0) {
      particles[i].vy = vy; // use vy instead of this.value
    }
  }
}
```

#### Demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "#323991");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "#000");

var flakes = 5;

var x = Math.random() * 800;
var y = 0;

var vx = 0;
var vy = 1;

var ground = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  ground.push(599);
}

var flakesControl = document.getElementById("flakes-control");
flakesControl.oninput = function() {
  flakes = this.value;
}

var gravityControl = document.getElementById("gravity-control");
gravityControl.oninput = function() {
  vy = +this.value;
  for(var i in particles) {
    if(particles[i].vy > 0) {
      particles[i].vy = vy;
    }
  }
}

var particles = {},
  particleIndex = 0,
  settings = {
    size: 1,
    density: 100
  }

function Particle() {
  this.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 800);
  this.y = y;
  this.vx = vx;
  this.vy = vy;
  particleIndex++;
  particles[particleIndex] = this;
  this.id = particleIndex;
}

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  if(this.y == ground[this.x]) {
    this.vy = 0;
    ground[this.x] = this.y - 1;
  } else { this.y += this.vy; }
  ctx.clearRect(settings.leftWall, settings.groundLevel, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,1,1);
}

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for(var i = 0; i < settings.density; i++) {
    if(Math.random() > (1 - (flakes / 1000))) {
      new Particle();
    }
  }

  for(var i in particles) {
    particles[i].draw();
  }
}, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<div id="controls">
  <div>
    <label for="flakes-control">Snowflakes: </label>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5" id="flakes-control" class="slider">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="gravity-control">Gravity: </label>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" id="gravity-control" class="slider">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So obvious. Thank you!!